# Unbalanced random number generator

Tags: c++, c, random

I have to pick an element from an ascending array. Smaller elements are considered better. So if I pick an element from the beginning of the array it's considered a better choice. But at the same time I don't want the choice to be deterministic and always the same element. So I'm looking for

> a random numbers generator that produces numbers in range [0, n], but
>   the smaller the number is, the more chance of it being produced.

This came to my mind:

```
num = n;
while(/*the more iteration the more chance for smaller numbers*/)
  num = rand()%num;
```

I was wondering if anyone had a better solution.
I did look at some similar questions but they have details about random number generation generally. I'm looking for a solution to this specific type of random number generation, either an algorithm or a library that provides it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207545/weighted-random-number-generation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a Random number, say `x`, between `[0,n)` and then generate another Random floating point number, say `y`, between `[0,1]`. Then raise x to the power of y and use floor function, you'll get your number.

```
int cust(int n)
{
  int x;
  double y, temp;
  x = rand() % n;
  y = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
  temp = pow((double) x, y);
  temp = floor(temp);
  return (int)temp;
}
```

Update: Here are some sample results of calling the above function 10 times, with n = 10, 20 and 30.

```
2 5 1 0 1 0 1 4 1 0

1 2 4 1 1 2 3 5 17 6

1 19 2 1 2 20 5 1 6 6
```

Comment: Thanks, this might work however, one quetion: How do I generate a number in range [0,1] in c++? `(rand()%n)/(float)n`?

Comment: Number from 0 to n: (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX * n)

Comment: @AtoMerZ- This will generate Random numbers with high probability.

Comment: Thanks again. This seems like a better solution since it only calls rand() once. I'll wait a bit for more answers, if nothing better comes up I'll accept.

Comment: Note that, regardless of `n`, `n - 1` will occur only once every `RAND_MAX` trials on average, which may be much smaller than you want (`RAND_MAX` is `2**31-1` on my machine, or about 2 billion).  You may wish to look into ways of fixing this exceedingly steep drop-off.

Answer (score 3):

Simple ad-hoc approach that came to my mind is to use standard random generators, but duplicate indices. So in the array:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3
```

odds are good that smaller element will be taken.
I dont' know exactly what do you need. You can also define your own distribution or maybe use some random number generation libraries. But suggested approach is simple and easy to configure.
**UPDATE2:** You don't have to generate array explicitly. For array of size 1000, you can generate random number from interval: [0,1000000] and then configure your own distribution of selected values: say, intervals of length 1200 for smaller values (0-500) and intervals of length 800 for larger (500-1000). The main point that this way you can easily configure the probability and you don't have to re-implement random number generator.

Comment: What you provide is almost impossible to implement if I have like 1000 numbers in my array.

Comment: Array was just an example. The main point is to change the interval for  smaller values. See Update2.

Comment: This is by far the best solution to implement a non-even distribution (especially weighted distribution). It takes minimal computation time and gives complete flexibility.

Comment: So bigger interval = more chance?

Comment: +1 Thanks, This is a good solution in general, but I think for this special case, mine is simpler and needs less configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I just made a suggestion and I have no idea what's more appropriate in this special case.

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriate random distribution, e.g. the rounded results of an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). Pick a distribution that fits your needs, document the distribution you used, and find a nice implementation. If code under the GNU Public License is an option, use the excellent GNU Scientific Library (GSL), or try Boost.Random.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I **only** understood Boost.Random. What's everything else?

Comment: @AtoMerZ: I expanded the acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

### Two tools will solve many random distribution needs

1) A uniform random number generator which you have

2) and a function which maps uniform values onto your target distribution

I've gotta head to the city now, but I'll make note to write up a couple of examples with a drawing when I get back.

There are some worthwhile methods and ideas discussed in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution) (more about generating a normal pseudo random number)